# Connect to Vertica from Spark 2.3.1 Scala 2.11.8 with jdbc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, vertica

I am trying to connect to a Vertica dB with Spark v2.3.1 Scala 2.11.8 using jdbc.

On the Vertica website: https://www.vertica.com/blog/whats-new-vertica-8-1-connector-apache-spark/

It says that I can download the Spark Connector at the following location: https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/8-1-x/

As I click to the link, it takes me to the log-in page, after I pass the log-in a yellow box pops at the top and says that I do not have permission to view that download.

I tried another route, this time to download from Vertica's download page. Under the Linux package there are 3 jar files (vertica-javadoc, vertica-jdbc, vertica-jdbc-8.0.1-0), but I cannot find the Vertica-Spark Connector (i.e.: vertica-8.1.0_spark2.0_scala2.11.jar). I downloaded the 3 jars.

In my Scala Eclipse IDE, I loaded the 3 jar files (vertica-javadoc, vertica-jdbc, vertica-jdbc-8.0.1-0), and used the following script to connect to Vertica:

```
val url = "jdbc:vertica//hostname/DBName?username=username&password=pw"

val query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE;"

val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("driver", "com.vertica.jdbc.Driver")
.option("url", url)
.option("dbtable", query)
.load()
```

And get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at att.com.vert2$.main(vert2.scala:37)
    at att.com.vert2.main(vert2.scala)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing the Vertica-Spark Connector? In case it is the Connector where can I download it from?

Cheers.

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SparkConnector/LoadingVerticaDataToSparkUsingVerticaDataSource.htm%3FTocPath%3DIntegrating%2520with%2520Apache%2520Spark%7CLoading%2520Vertica%2520Data%2520into%2520a%2520Spark%2520DataFrame%2520or%2520RDD%7C_____1) how to load to scala dataframe or [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-jdbc-connection-mysql-sql-select-example) for scala jdbc connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The issue was in the syntax:

```
val url = "jdbc:vertica//hostname/DBName?username=username&password=pw"
```

It was missing a : (Colon) between vertica and //. 
Changed from username to user.
And added the Port Number after hostname.

The working syntax is:

```
val url = "jdbc:vertica://hostname:Port/DBName?user=youruser&password=yourpassword"
```